# Как выровнять высоту 3 блоков по родительскому контейнеру?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Вот конкретный раздел сайта над которым я работаю:

[Вот сайт](https://onedaytv.ru/#service)

У меня есть 3 блока с услугами. В данный момент все они имеют высоту в зависимости от контента. Мне необходимо выровнять их высоту по самому большому из этих блоков, а также разместить кнопку "Узнать прайс" внизу блока с отступом в 20 пикселей от нижней части. Помогите пожалуйста это сделать. Уже пол дня играюсь с position:relative, absolute для родителей и child блоков и никак не могу получить нужный результат.

Comment: http://ru.learnlayout.com/clearfix.html

Comment: @Almost не все так просто

Comment: @Almost и при чем же тут clearfix?

Comment: @iSeeDev добавьте код этого раздела в вопрос

Comment: могу подсказать как на js написать скрипт. А так просто задай min-hieght

Comment: @Cheg добавить могу, но вот я думаю удобнее было бы перейти на сайт и в исходном коде все увидеть и там же если вы можете поправить css

Comment: @Philip Pilipchuk на js я тоже сделал, но возможно есть решение на css, также интересует вторая часть вопроса, как примагнитить кнопку к низу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать `flexbox` для раздела и `position:absolute` - для кнопки:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block {
  width: calc((100% - 126px) / 3);
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div class="btn">Кнопка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div class="btn">Кнопка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div class="btn">Кнопка</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Супер! Большое вам спасибо! Мне подошло ваше решение!